# How to make my ant design Header name dynamic according to the content component rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, antd, ant-design-pro

I am working on a project using ant design where I have created a separate header and the content components.

This is my header component.

```
import React from "react";
import { Layout, Avatar, Row, Col, Popover, Button, Badge } from "antd";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { BellIcon, LeftArrowIcon } from "../../assets/svg/icons";
import { PoweroffOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import "./Header.css";
import { logout } from "../../actions/userActions";
const { Header } = Layout;

const GoBack = () => {
  return window.history.back();
};

const CustomHeader = withRouter((props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { location } = props;
  let title = "";
  /*Header Dynamic Titles*/

  if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/home") {
    title = "Home";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/clients") {
    title = "Clients";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/inventory") {
    title = "Inventory";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/marketing") {
    title = "Marketing";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/clients/appointment/new") {
    title = "New Appointment";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/checkout") {
    title = "Checkout";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/clients") {
    title = "Clients Profile";
  }
  return (
    <Header
      style={{
        position: "sticky",
        top: 0,
        zIndex: 1,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        paddingLeft: "1.1rem",
      }}
    >
      <Row>
        <Col order={1}>
          {location.pathname === "/dashboard/appointment/new" ? (
            <strong style={{ fontSize: "1.1rem" }}>
              <LeftArrowIcon style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }} onClick={GoBack} />
              {title}
            </strong>
          ) : location.pathname === "/dashboard/checkout" ? (
            <strong style={{ fontSize: "1.1rem" }}>
              <LeftArrowIcon style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }} onClick={GoBack} />
              {title}
            </strong>
          ) : (
            <strong style={{ fontSize: "1.1rem" }}> {title}</strong>
          )}
        </Col>
        <Col
          style={{
            marginLeft: "auto",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
          xxl={1}
          xs={1}
          sm={1}
          md={1}
          lg={1}
          order={2}
        >
          <Badge count={0}>
            <BellIcon shape='square' style={{ marginLeft: "2.9vw" }} />
          </Badge>
        </Col>
        <Col xxl={4} xs={4} sm={4} md={4} lg={5} order={3}>
          <Popover content={avtarDetails(dispatch)}>
            <Avatar
              style={{
                color: "#fff",
                backgroundColor: "purple",
                marginLeft: "6vw",
              }}
            >
              G
            </Avatar>
          </Popover>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Header>
  );
});

export default CustomHeader;
```

currently, I am locating the router path name and making the headers dynamic.
For example,

```
if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/home") {
    title = "Home";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/clients") {
    title = "Clients";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/billing") {
    title = "Billing";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/clients/appointment/new") {
    title = "New Appointment";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/checkout") {
    title = "Checkout";
  } else if (location.pathname === "/dashboard/clients") {
    title = "Clients Profile";
  }
```

[header Location and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY1sw.png)
[Header names through location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeDIZ.png)

[I want New Appointment as the header title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXhuc.png)

I want to display header name as New Appoint in the path location which can be obtained if the location url is

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/clients/appointment/new
```

but in production i am assigning unique id between the location url

Example:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/clients/6000459f0682ed4590889067/appointment/new
```

Here 6000459f0682ed4590889067 is the unique id of the client, for every individual client the id will be unique. Now how can I set the header dynamic name as New Appointment.

Please help me resolve this. Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex.

```
^\/dashboard\/clients\/[A-Za-z0-9]{24}\/appointment\/new*$
```

https://regexr.com/5kdju